# insert into select from inner join where not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL Server code. Everything works except it duplicates rows with same `RightsId` and `UserId`. The `where not exists` clause is not working.
Any help is appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserAccessRights (Id, UserId, RightType, RightsId, CreatedOn, CreatedBy)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        NEWID(),
        @changedUserId,
        N'Process ' + @rightsTypeSuffix,
        ptm.ProcessInstance_id,
        getdate(),
        @loggedInUserId
    FROM 
        dbo.ProcessTeamMembers ptm WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Users u WITH (NOLOCK) ON ptm.TeamMemberProfile_id = u.ProfileID
                                  AND u.Id = @changedUserId
                                  AND ptm.TenantId = @tenantId
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.ProcessInstances p_i WITH (NOLOCK) ON p_i.Id = ptm.ProcessInstance_id
                                               AND p_i.DeletedOn IS NULL
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM UserAccessRights uar WITH (NOLOCK) 
                    WHERE uar.UserId = @changedUserId 
                      AND uar.RightsId = ptm.ProcessInstance_id)
```

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: So the (NOLOCK) is the problem with the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your duplicates are probably coming from within the query, rather than from existing rows in the table.  Possibly, the problem is that the `select distinct` isn't doing anything -- because `newid()` is always unique.

My recommendation is to change the `id` column to have a default value of `newid()`.  Then you don't need to insert it and the `select distinct` will work.  Absent that, you can fix the query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserAccessRights (Id, UserId, RightType, RightsId, CreatedOn, CreatedBy)
    SELECT DISTINCT NEWID(), @changedUserId, N'Process ' + @rightsTypeSuffix,
           ProcessInstance_id, getdate(), @loggedInUserId
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ptm.ProcessInstance_id
          FROM dbo.ProcessTeamMembers ptm WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN 
               dbo.Users u WITH (NOLOCK)
               ON ptm.TeamMemberProfile_id = u.ProfileID AND
                  u.Id = @changedUserId AND
                ptm.TenantId = @tenantId INNER JOIN 
               dbo.ProcessInstances p_i WITH (NOLOCK)
               ON p_i.Id = ptm.ProcessInstance_id AND
                  p_i.DeletedOn IS NULL
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM UserAccessRights uar WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            WHERE uar.UserId = @changedUserId AND   
                                  uar.RightsId = ptm.ProcessInstance_id
                           )
    ) t;
```

Hmmm, as I think about this, perhaps you should be using `TOP 1` rather than `SELECT DISTINCT`.  I'm not sure which columns cause the problem on the distinct, but you are inserting the same value in many columns, so more than one row might cause an issue.

Comment: We would probably need to see his schema and sample data that produces the problem in order to better diagnose the multiple rows issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Left Excluding Join" (See [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)) instead of the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UserAccessRights (Id, UserId, RightType, RightsId, CreatedOn, CreatedBy)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        NEWID(),
        @changedUserId,
        N'Process ' + @rightsTypeSuffix,
        ptm.ProcessInstance_id,
        getdate(),
        @loggedInUserId
    FROM 
        dbo.ProcessTeamMembers ptm 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Users u ON ptm.TeamMemberProfile_id = u.ProfileID
                                  AND u.Id = @changedUserId
                                  AND ptm.TenantId = @tenantId
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.ProcessInstances p_i ON p_i.Id = ptm.ProcessInstance_id
                                               AND p_i.DeletedOn IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN UserAccessRights uar
        ON uar.UserId = u.Id
            AND uar.RightsId = ptm.ProcessInstance_id
    WHERE 
        uar.Id IS NULL -- Replace with the actual pkey on UserAccessRights if not Id
```